# Create cone gradient like in google maps in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, bitmap, gradient

I want my end result to be something like this

[image]

and my 3 requirements are

1. Control the color
2. Control the angle of the cone
3. Control the degree how "wide" the angle is(between 0-360)

My code is as follows

```
 internal static Bitmap Generate()
        {
            int width = 160;
            int height = 160;
            var color1 = CreateRandomShare(Color.AliceBlue);
            var color2 = CreateRandomShare(Color.Navy);
            var bitmap = GenerateGradient(color1, color2, width, height, LinearGradientMode.BackwardDiagonal);
            bitmap.Save("test.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);

            return bitmap;

        }

 private static Color CreateRandomShare(Color color)
        {
            const int range = 1000;
            const int variance = 700;
            var random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            int factor = random.Next(range - variance, range + variance + 1);
            int r = color.R + factor / range;
            int g = color.G + factor / range;
            int b = color.B + factor / range;

            return Color.FromArgb(255, Math.Min(r, 255), Math.Min(g, 255), Math.Min(b, 255));

        }

        private static Bitmap GenerateGradient(Color color1, Color color2, int width, int height, LinearGradientMode mode)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), color1, color2, mode);
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            PointF[] points =
            {
                new (50, 50),
                new (100, 25),
                new (200, 5),
                new (250, 5),
                new (300, 100),
                new (350, 200),
                new (250, 250),
            };


            g.FillPolygon(brush, points);
            return bmp;
        }
```

and my final result

[image]

which is kind of close

my problem is that I do not know how to meet requirements (2) and (3)

Comment: That's not a "cone" or conical gradient - that's [a circular-segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector) of [a radial gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mainly two tasks we must solve:

1. Draw a sector, i.e. a shape looking like a piece of a pizza.
2. Draw a radial gradient.

Let's create a method with this signature where the angles are measured in degrees (360 degrees = one full turn):

```cs
private static void DrawSector(Graphics g, Rectangle rect,
    float startAngle, float sweepAngle, Color color)
```

Let's also calculate these angles in radians as input for trigonometric functions as well as a few other values we will need later:

```cs
float startAngleRadians = startAngle * MathF.PI / 180f;
float endAngleRadians = (startAngle + sweepAngle) * MathF.PI / 180f;

float radius = 0.5f * rect.Width;
float centerX = rect.X + radius;
float centerY = rect.Y + radius;
```

To draw a sector, we can construct a path consisting of:

1. a radial line starting at the center and going towards the start of an arc
2. an arc segment
3. a line starting at the end of the arc going back to the center

The same path will be used to draw the shape and to define a `PathGradientBrush`.

```cs
var center = new PointF(centerX, centerY);
var startOfArc = new PointF(
    centerX + radius * MathF.Cos(startAngleRadians),
    centerY + radius * MathF.Sin(startAngleRadians));
var endOfArc = new PointF(
    centerX + radius * MathF.Cos(endAngleRadians),
    centerY + radius * MathF.Sin(endAngleRadians));

using var path = new GraphicsPath();
path.AddLine(center, startOfArc);
path.AddArc(rect, startAngle, sweepAngle);
path.AddLine(endOfArc, center);
```

Now, let's define a gradient brush. We are using the same color as start color and end color, but we make the end color transparent, so that the sector will fade out gradually revealing more and more of the background.

Then all we have to do, is to draw the path with this gradient brush:

```cs
using var brush = new PathGradientBrush(path) {
    CenterColor = color,
    CenterPoint = center,
    SurroundColors = new[] { Color.FromArgb(0, color) }
};
g.FillPath(brush, path);
```

For testing, let's call it in an empty WinForms form like this:

```cs
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black);
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

    // Create a centered square
    int length = Math.Min(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height) - 6;
    int dx = (ClientSize.Width - length) / 2;
    int dy = (ClientSize.Height - length) / 2;
    var rect = new Rectangle(dx, dy, length, length);

    // Create a sector with a random sweep angle pointing upwards
    float sweepAngle = Random.Shared.NextSingle() * 360;
    float startAngle = -90f - 0.5f * sweepAngle;
    DrawSector(e.Graphics, rect, startAngle, sweepAngle, Color.Blue);
}
```

Let's also add a click event handler to redraw the arc with other random settings (make sure it is wired up):

```cs
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Invalidate();
}
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

Note: `Random.Shared` exists since .NET 6. For older .NET versions, just create a random object yourself.

Comment: Okay, I see. But since the OP is generating a Bitmap with `System.Drawing`, this method (`DrawSector`) can still be used. He is creating a `Graphics` object from a bitmap instead of using the one from `OnPaint`. That's the major difference.

Comment: Sorry, the question does not seem to be about WPF. I have edited the tags.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thanks, but I'm using WPF i used `System.Drawing` because it was easier for me to save it to an image

Comment: It is not clear to me what you need. Do you need a Bitmap that you want to use in WPF or do you need a XAML-solution not involving any Bitmap? (If you need the latter, why show code creating a Bitmap?)